# Re-creating A vector logo - missing fonts

Tags: font-identification

I have to re-create a vector version of this low-res logo but would so appreciate if anyone can help track down what fonts it includes?

I've tried all the match-my-font etc. sites with little luck.

Seems to be three fonts total being used.

(top Historic + Burger Bar are the same)

[image: font]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Big Noodle Titling Font](https://www.dafont.com/bignoodletitling.font)

[image]

[Fairweather](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/flat-it/fairweather/) from myfonts.com (similar but not the same)
[image]

[Airstream Font](https://www.dafont.com/search.php?q=airstream) from dafont.com

[image]